# Disable Session.checkAgent for one action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have built a controller that is uses the media view to stream videos to users. When someone accesses the controller from an iOS device, the user agent being sent is not matching and the session logs out.

I am using the iPad plugin for Flow Player and I have seen other posts about flash not sending the correct user agent strings, so instead of messing with that, I'd like to disable Session.checkAgent for that specific action. I have tried adding it to beforeFilter(), but the check clearly happens before that point.

Is there some other method I can override to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but if you know (part of) the URL, you can check the `$_GET['url']` inside your app/Config/core.php and modify the session configuration based upon its value, For example, `$_GET['url']` starts with '/videos/view'.

You need to do this inside the configuration file, otherwise the session is already started as you already discovered.

Note that `$_GET['url']` is only used in older versions of CakePHP. For newer versions of CakePHP, you may need to user `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or another `$_SERVER` environment variable.